# How to use local macbook server to allow multiple devices to view Reactjs page?

Tags: reactjs, router

I have a local server running Reactjs on my Macbook. (newbie in React)

1) How could I change the http://localhost:4001 name to something else (e.g. http://www.test.com)
--> I'm using `webpack-dev-server --port 4001`

2) How could I allow up to 500 iOS/Android device to connect to this local server? (e.g do how to setup a router to broadcast this?)

--> Found this [ReactJS-and-ngrok](http://www.davidboyne.co.uk/2016/11/21/ReactJS-and-ngrok.html) but not sure what's the concurrent users it's able to support.

3) How to allow the device to connect to a wifi without internet access?

Comment: Thx @MayankShukla, what's a more suitable tag? Btw, what's the maximum number of concurrent device?

Answer (score 2):

First, see what IP is your Macbook in your local network. System Preferences->Network. Suppose your Macbook IP is 192.168.1.70 and your server is on 4001 port. Then you can start your webpack-dev-server with the following options: `--output-public-path="http://192.168.1.70:4001/" --host="0.0.0.0" --public="192.168.1.70:4001"`. You can still access it via `localhost` name on Macbook, but on other devices use full IP + port number as address.

[image]

Can't say anything about setting domain... may be you can configure your router somehow? Sorry, newer had to face such a task

Comment: Thanks GProst, the ipad is able to open the website. However, it's not able to connect to Golang server and Rethink DB. I'm using "go run *go" and "rethinkdb" to start these 2 local servers

Comment: Can't say anything about these, try to look in documentation about why not able to connect. Maybe you should set specific IP instead of `localhost` for these servers or some other options.